# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I tried to upgrade my web app from .net core 2.0 to .net core 2.1
I did:

1) Install Visual Studio Professional 2017 Preview Version 15.8.0 Preview 1.1
2) Installed the .net core 2.1.3 RC1 SDK from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-rc1
3) Updated all of my aspnetcore nuget packages to the latest version.

After doing both of these things, when I start my project I get this screen:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure Common causes of this issue:
>
> ```
> The application process failed to start
> The application process started but then stopped
> The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
> ```
>
> Troubleshooting steps:
>
> ```
> Check the system event log for error messages
> Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
> Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
> ```
>
> For more information visit:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

and in my Output window from ASP.NET Core Web Server, I get this:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      2.1.0-preview2-final at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.1.0-rc1-final at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
  - The following versions are installed:
      2.1.0-preview2-final at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      2.1.0-rc1-final at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

Comment: Apparently they released the nuget packages that rely on the sdk before they released the sdk.  Frustrating!

Comment: @GeekyMonkey What would possess them to do such a thing? 

Comment: .NET SDK 2.1.300 is now available:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows
Please install it, should address this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.NET Core 2.1 SDK will be released this week. If you can't wait until then, add this to your *.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
        https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/orchestrated-release-2-1/20180515-07/final/index.json
    </RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  ....
</Project>
```

And download the final SDK from: https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.300/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-win-x64.exe

For more details visit: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads

Answer (score 8):

By updating all NuGet packages, you seem to have upgraded from the RC version you started out with (which is installed on your system) to the RTM version currently being released (and thus already available on NuGet but not installed on your system).

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` NuGet packages are supposed to be referenced without a version so that the installed tooling can pick an appropriate version.

Update your .csproj file to remove the `Version` attribute and only reference that package through:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: "supposed to be referenced without a version" I disagree with this statement. Besides, your suggestion doesn't work because the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App NuGet package doesn't contain an inclusive lower bound. My suggestion is to wait until the final .NET SDK 2.1.300 installer is available to install the latest ASP.NET Core 2.1 bits.

Comment: The Web SDK (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`) will take over choosing the appropriate version for the package reference in 2.1. In a recent change they added the flag that will prevent the NuGet dialog from offering version updates. it will behave similar to the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package which is referenced behind the scenes but the web sdk needs to let users choose between the `M…AspNetCore.App` and `M…AspNetCore.All` package this way

Comment: e.g. have a look at what the templates now create for 2.1 projects (using `dotnet new mvc` with the 2.1.300 SDK for example)

Comment: @MagnusJohansson, I have installed 2.1.300 - but it still does leads to the situation described in the topic. However Martin's solution did the trick.

Comment: Update 8 July 2018. https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6430 "After reviewing customer feedback and lots of design discussion, we think the implicit package version has created more confusion than help. We are planning to change course and go back to recommending using the Version attribute on the PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/All."

Comment: yes and the change was planned for 2.1.3 but they backed out again, trying to rethink it for 2.2

Answer (score 5):

.NET Core SDK 2.1.300 is now available: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows Install it, this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's available on chocolatey now https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-sdk/2.1.300

Not yet on the normal dotnet distribution sites. Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

1. uninstall previous version
2. Download and install version 2.1 sdk
3. After the whole process reboot your PC

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the Visual Studio installer, went to **Individual Components**, selected **.NET Core 2.1 Runtime (LTS)**, and installed it.

Solved my problem.

[image]