# .Net Core lastest SDK installed but getting 'Framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, archlinux

I want to use .Net Core on linux and do have the latest releases:

```
> sudo pacman -Qs dotnet
local/dotnet-host 2.1.0-1
    A generic driver for the .NET Core Command Line Interface
local/dotnet-runtime 2.1.0-1
    The .NET Core runtime
local/dotnet-sdk 2.1.300-1
    The .NET Core SDK
> dotnet --version
2.1.300
```

But when I want to run my sample application (just the razor template):

```
> dotnet run  
Using launch settings from /home/user/src/WebRepTrack/Properties/launchSettings.json...
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /opt/dotnet/
  - Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
  - The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Looking at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594020/the-specified-framework-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-version-2-1-0-was-not-foun), the problem was that the user did not have the appropiate sdk/runtime version installed, but that's not the cause of my issue, isnt it?

Edit: After looking into the dotnet-core repo at github, I realized that MS now ships the asp.net core support with the package aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0 (whereas before, it was shipped with the core-runtime). The ArchLinux package `dotnet-runtime` **does not** include this change! See here for more details:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58806

Comment: If you delete the `launchSettings.json` file, does that help at all? (Just guessing at the moment.)

Comment: Unfortunately not, it didnt help at all. But thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking into the dotnet-core repo at github, I realized that MS now ships the asp.net core support with the [package](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.1.0-download.md) `aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0` (whereas before, it was shipped with the core-runtime). The ArchLinux package `dotnet-runtime` **does not** include this change! See [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/58806) for more details:

Comment: i'm facing the same issue.. so what should i do to fix it ?